# Does the quartz scheduler delete triggers?

Tags: java, c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I basically want to know, if the scheduler itself deletes triggers after they have fired if there are not any other points in time where they would ever fire again?
I need to know this so that I know how to tidy up after a job has been executed.

I have already read through many posts about triggers and jobs. I have also read through all the official quartz lessons. Only thing I found out there was that jobs can be deleted if you set their property "durable" to false when there are no more triggers pointing to it.. That is also how my question came up on how or when the scheduler deletes its triggers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it automatically removes these triggers.
I've found some documentation for this topic: https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/SimpleTrigger.html

there is a line stating:

> **int   getRepeatCount()**
> Get the the number of times the SimpleTrigger should repeat, after which it will be automatically deleted.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you have any source for this?